# Css responsive image issue

Tags: html, css, image

[image]
Please look at the attached image to see the problem.
I want the image to stay centered to the rectangle beneath it no matter the browser window size.
When I resize the browser, the image does not keep the aspect ratio regarding to the rectangle beneath it. 
How can I make the image resize with respect to the rectangle beneath it?
I tried searching the net, but found nothing.

```css
body{
 background-color: #fcab55;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
 width: 900px;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 1px slid red;
 max-width: 100%;
}



.pizza_img_background{
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 900px;
 height: 225px;
 background-color: #010606;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.pizza{
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 855px;
 height: 192px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 22.5px;
 margin-right: 22.5px;
 background-image: url("images/pizza.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
  <body>
   <header>
   </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="pizza_img_background">
    <img src="images/pizza.png" alt="Pizza " class="pizza">
   </div>

  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're setting it up as a background image rather than just using the `img` element?

Comment: … and why the “rectangle beneath” is not just a simple border or box-shadow?

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height of `.pizza` to `100%` instead of a fixed width?

Comment: Good question. I wanted to change the color of the background when  I hover the image with the mouse. I tried making one image with black borders, but it does not resale with the current code.

Comment: @APAD1 <img> elements are not as easily scalable to various window sizes.

Comment: @MrLister how do you figure?

Comment: I did try to use 100% width and height, but it did not work.

Comment: @APAD1 You can't have an img that is contained in a window, and also keeps the h/w ratio, the same way a background image can. Try it.

Comment: Mr Lister so you suggest to have one image with the black borders? Then why does the code not work when I repace the image whit the other one and change the with to 900px?

Comment: Look to my answer please Catalin Borz, i dont know if will help you but...

Comment: You could use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to give especific values between size transitions... `max-width: 100%; width: 855px;` sounds like you can spend as much as you want but only $30...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
margin-left: 22.5px;
margin-right: 22.5px;
width: 855px;
```

to

```
padding-left: 22.5px;
padding-right: 22.5px;
width: 100%;
```

Here is a codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZVKdJ

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you so much. It was exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I changed from your code is the height. I don't want the height to change. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty unclear, is this what you're looking for?

```css
.pizza {
  text-align:center;
}
.img-container {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
  padding:20px;
}
  .img-container:hover {
    background:#ccc;
  }
  .img-container img {
    max-width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pizza">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempizza.com/640/480" alt="Pizza" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had problems when residing the browser window. The image did not keep the aspect ratio with regard with the beneath rectangle. I had one image whit the Pizza and a Css rectangle under it...

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You are also right. Thank you! Have a pleasant day everyone.